# Nginx proxy url to fingerprinted stylesheet

Tags: regex, nginx, proxy

I'm trying to use nginx as a proxy for compiled assets served by a jekyll site because I share some of these assets across multiple sites and apps. I'd like to have a /css/main.css that is a proxy or rewrite to /assets/main-*.css (where * is the fingerprint which changes relatively frequently). This is the direction I'm currently heading:

```
rewrite ^/css/main.css$ /assets/main-(.*).css last;
```

But that doesn't work (returns 404). Anyone know how to write this to use some sort of wildcard or regex for the fingerprinted part of the stylesheet url? Or have tips on a better way to do this?

Comment: Rewrite with wildcard doesn't help and produces caching problems that's why file name with fingerprint in it is so handy. Why not to serve main-*.css directly as thousand of other Rails apps do?

Comment: Because I want to use those assets from other sites and apps without having to update the fingerprint in every single one.

Comment: Have you tried to symlink yet?

Comment: not yet, i'll try your answer soon though. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sym link after deployment is complete solves the problem:

```
ln -sf /your/dir/assets/main-*.css /your/dir/css/main.css
```

In any case you face a caching problem because fingerprinting tends to solve that issue. E-Tag can help but file may be cached somewhere in transit from server to the browser.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Totally understand the caching issue, but I just need this temporary solution while we refactor the structure of our shared assets. This is perfect for now =]